# Play a list of image urls as a video in html5

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video

I have a list of image urls that are backups images taken from a security camera.  They are served behind an nginx proxy.

Is there a way to play the images as if they were a video?  I am currently appending 10 images at a time to a div and using the z-index to display one at a time.

But I want a better way, that lets me use the built in  controls.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
["http://0.0.0.0:7733/1/2/2018-08-14_18-44-51.jpg", "http://0.0.0.0:7733/1/2/2018-08-14_18-44-52.jpg", "http://0.0.0.0:7733/1/2/2018-08-14_18-44-53.jpg", "http://0.0.0.0:7733/1/2/2018-08-14_18-44-54.jpg", "http://0.0.0.0:7733/1/2/2018-08-14_18-44-55.jpg", "http://0.0.0.0:7733/1/2/2018-08-14_18-44-56.jpg", "http://0.0.0.0:7733/1/2/2018-08-14_18-44-57.jpg", "http://0.0.0.0:7733/1/2/2018-08-14_18-44-58.jpg", "http://0.0.0.0:7733/1/2/2018-08-14_18-44-59.jpg", "http://0.0.0.0:7733/1/2/2018-08-14_18-45-00.jpg"]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to play the images as if they were a video?

Not directly, no.  You would have to create a video and either load it via MediaSource Extensions or as a regular Blob.  That's going to require a codec and what not, since your source format is JPEG.

> But I want a better way, that lets me use the built in controls.

Emulating controls of a video player is going to be much easier than messing with a video.

> using the z-index to display one at a time

I'd use `visibility: hidden` instead.  If you just have a bunch of images stacked and are changing the `z-index`, you're likely creating a lot of work for the browser as it's going to put these on different layers and composite them all together later, even if a particular frame isn't seen.  (Check the performance in your developer tools, experiment, and see.)

If you really want to create a video out of these, it is possible but a bit nasty:

1. Create a canvas element.
2. Use CanvasCaptureMediaStream to get a MediaStream from the canvas contents.
3. Use MediaRecorder to record that MediaStream into something manageable, like a VP9 video in WebM.

Even after that, you're going to have to hack the resulting WebM a bit to get it to play in-browser, but it will work.